# File Uploading in Selenium Controlled Browser

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, ubuntu-14.04

I want to upload a file in Selenium Controlled Chrome Browser using python running over Ubuntu14. 
I have seen some answers to select element and send keys but that does not work for Ubuntu/MAC OS since it does not have any element to receive keys. Other solutions suggested Skilui and similar but they are either Jython specific tools and I'm not familiar with them either.
OS: Ubuntu 14 32-bit
Language: Python 3.4
Driver: Selenium Web Driver
Browser: Chrome

HTML code:

```
<div class="osInfo" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: uploadFile">
    <div class="ccFontccIcon ic_ic-upload" title="Upload OS Image" data-dojo-attach-point="imageUploadBtn"></div>
    <div class="osFileName" data-dojo-attach-point="imageName">
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="imageFileName">Drag and drop a file here or <span>Select a file from your computer</span></span>
    </div>
    <!--<input data-dojo-attach-point="stateSelect">-->
</div>
```

I tried something similar to following:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("fileUpload").send_keys("C:\myfile.txt")
```

Actual code:

```
mode = '4321'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='iosrRepeaterItem empty' and descendant::*[@class='pid-item' " + "and contains(text(), '" + model + "')]]//div[@class='osInfo']").send_keys("/Users/mushoaib/Downloads/car-for-sale\ \(2\).pdf").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Above code works to the point of clicking on upload dialog but after that, it does not do anything.

Any help will be really appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.